# Zenfone3 doesn't show my icon

Tags: android

I have a trouble with my app. I use Android Studio, and I tested it on the Asus Zenfone 3 (Android vers. 5.0.2). When I intall my app, my smartphone doesn't show my customize icon.

I already checked into my manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/klain"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/klain"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".KlainRoboticsMir"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <actions android:name="android.intent.actions.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".BackgroundMir"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </service>


    <receiver
        android:name=".AlarmManagerServiceBattery"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
    </receiver>
</application>
```

and I have the correct mipmap resource because I see my image how preview:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QcH3.png)

Have you some ideas where is my fault?

Thanks very much

Comment: add this line in application tag `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`

Comment: Ok thanks...but what is this?